# Get file from an API running with Flask in Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, api, flask

I have a python API running with Flask and a web application running with Spring.

The API has a route `GET /zip_file/zip_name` that return the zip file using the flask `send_file` function.

The Web Application must allow the user to download this file.

I did that:

```
    // Get the job's route url.
    String resourceUrl = ApiConfig.URL + "/" + ApiConfig.MODEL_ROUTE  + "/" + modelName;

    // Create the request.
    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

    // Execute the request.
    ResponseEntity<String> res = restTemplate.getForEntity(resourceUrl, String.class);

    // Send the file to the user the returned zip file.
    String content = res.getBody();
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(content.getBytes());
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + modelName)
            .contentLength(content.length())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
            .body(resource);
```

Unfortunatly, the archive receive is not a valid one.

Why ? How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to directly return the responces received from flask:

```
@GetMapping("/download_file")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadFile(@RequestParam("file_name") String fileName, Model model) {

    // Get the job's route url.
    String resourceUrl = ApiConfig.URL + "/" + ApiConfig.FILE_ROUTE  + "/" + fileName;

    // Create the request.
    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

    // Execute the request.
    return restTemplate.getForEntity(resourceUrl, ByteArrayResource.class);
}
```